# woocommerce_product_query hook with Elementor products tab

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

the following hook

```
function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {


$tempAddress = $_COOKIE["tempAddress"];
$categories_to_exclude = array();

if (strpos($tempAddress, 'New York') !== FALSE)
    {
        //categories_to_exclude;
        //$q->set(); 
    }

else
    {
        $args = apply_filters('woocommerce_related_products_args', 
        array(
            'post_type'             => 'product',
            'post_status'           => 'publish',
            'meta_query'            => array(
                 array(
                    'key'           => '_visibility',
                    'value'         => array('catalog', 'visible'),
                    'compare'       => 'IN'
                ),
            ),
            'tax_query'            => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field'    => 'term_id', // Or 'name' or 'term_id'
                    'terms'    => array(51,52,53),
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN', // Excluded
                )
            )
        ) 
    );
    
    $q->set( 'tax_query', $args ); 
}}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );
```

helps us remove the products of certain categories in WooCommerce. However, when the theme has Elementor products tab on a certain page (for example the home page), the hook is not applied.

Any idea?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution? I have currently the same problem.